# Facebook: Get when user clicks like button on fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created an app that will be used as a tab on my company facebook fan page. I have a new requirement to capture when the user clicks the like button on the facebook fan page and hide a portion of the app page (within the iframe) when the event fires.  Although the like button is on facebook's page, is there a way to capture the click event of the like button (ie: javascript sdk) within my app iframe so I can hide appropriate elements?

Like this .... http://www.facebook.com/redbull

Thanks for any and all advice,
B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer...
[How to detect Facebook Like button pressed and trigger event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885487/how-to-detect-facebook-like-button-pressed-and-trigger-event)

I checked the incoming request for fb_sig_is_fan.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that this is not possible. Also it makes no sense! because Facebook will reload the page once you click on the like button!

Comment: @bflemi3: Maybe you have a fast connection or something, but the Page is getting reloaded before the "Like us" overlay is disappearing!